# MongoDB no localhost request is working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I set up a MEAN-App which runs on a Debian 8 Server. Node and the full mongodb-org packages are installed and everything works fine so far.

If i now like to do a login or register inside my application my requests are not working. My login uses the route

```
http://localhost:3000/users/authenticate
```

but when i click on login, there is no answer from the mongodb. Inside my `mongod.conf` file i already tried many things with `bindIp` but nothing worked so far.

If i change `localhost` to the ip address of the machine (192.168.55.132) everything works like a charme but i think thats not right?!

How do i solve the problem, so that the DB is accepting the requests?

Comment: Try `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost` ?

Comment: Doesn't work hmm...

Comment: How do you connect to Mongo? What URL?

Comment: You mean, you are sending requests to `localhost` from client and server running on someother machine ? how is that supposed to work ?

Comment: are you serving your front end from node ? is node on the same server as mongdb ?